# Login dialog of StackExchange doesn't offer fields for email and password in WebKit based browsers

Tags: discussion, javascript, design, login, webkit

I don't use Google, Facebook, Yahoo or OpenID. So I login to my new StackExchange-Account via the login-dialog of StackExchange itself.

```
Don't have an account?

-> click here to sign up

If you’ve forgotten or lost your login information

-> click here to recover your account
```

Within Firefox I see a regular option for entering my login-data above this. It seems to me, that the necessary option/fields are loaded asynchronous after the other options and inserted at the top. But this fields are not loaded in Epiphany or Midori. With the official browser of Android (also WebKit) it works, but the mobile-website itself is designed in an other way.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just after registering.
Logging in with Internet Explorer works fine, in Opera there are no input fields.

Here's a workaround to log in:

1. Go to http://openid.stackexchange.com
2. Copy the URL given for logging into OpenID services
3. Click "log in" on any stackexchange website such as stackoverflow
4. Instead of choosing stackexchange as a login method, click "Show more login options"
5. Paste the URL copied in step 2
6. When you now try to log in, you will be redirected and input fields will be present

Comment: Note that just using http://openid.stackexchange.com in step 5 works as well.